# LEFT JOIN - вытащить все совпадения

Tags: mysql, mysqli

```
news
+-------+----------------+-----------
|   ID  |   name         |   tag_ID  
+-------+----------------+-----------
|   1   |   SIMPLE1      |   1,2
+-------+----------------+-----------
|   2   |   SIMPLE2      |   3
+-------+----------------+-----------
|   3   |   SIMPLE3      |   
+-------+----------------+-----------
tag  
+-------+----------------+
|   ID  |   name         |
+-------+----------------+
|   1   |   SIMPLE5      |
+-------+----------------+
|   2   |   SIMPLE6      |
+-------+----------------+
|   3   |   SIMPLE7      |
+-------+----------------+

SELECT n.*, t.name  as ttt
   FROM news n
   LEFT JOIN tag t ON t.id in(tag)      
   where  n.id = 1
```

Почему вытаскивает только одну запись, как сделать чтобы вытащила все совпадения. Все записи, чтобы на выходе получить массив в массиве. То есть поле содержало результат в виде массива из второй таблицы. Что только уже не перепробовал.

Comment: Вы этим `ON t.id in(tag)` что хотели сделать? Совпадение по каким полям должно быть?

Comment: В первой таблице, поле `tag_ID` содержит `1,2` id записей из второй таблицы. Необходимо вытащить все записи из второй таблиц по данным id

Comment: `SELECT news.* FROM news JOIN tag ON news.tag_id = tag.id;`

Comment: Не работает tag.id содержит строчку, список id из второй таблицы. Если бы поле содержало 1 id, тогда работало бы, а так как содержит несколько. Так не работает

Comment: ```.. ON FIND_IN_SET(tag.id, news.tag_id) ..```. Но это будет fullscan. Нормализуйте структуру.

Comment: Что  так, что через `ON t.id in(tag)`. Выхватывает только одну строчку из второй таблицы, а не две как указано в поле `tag_ID`