# Запрос в цикле, вместо двух циклов один

Tags: mysqli

```
$bd->query("sql");
while($r = $bd->get_array())
    print_r($value);
```

В некоторых случаях, необходимо выполнить запрос в цикле

```
$bd->query("sql");
while($r = $bd->get_array())
    $bd->query("sql");
```

Выдает ошибку, тогда делаю так

```
$bd->query("sql");
while($r = $bd->get_array())
    $ms[] = $r;

foreach ($ms as $key => $value) {
    $bd->query("sql");
}
```

Так работает. Вопрос в том, возможно ли выполнить запрос сразу как это во втором примере. Быть может я не знаю такого способа. Дабы лишний раз не собирать массив и по новой в цикле не прогонять...

Comment: query сбрасывает результат предыдущего запроса.

Comment: примеры запросов добавьте, непонятно что хотите сделать.

Comment: Так может надо просто правильный запрос составить, тогда не придется циклом в БД ходить?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1494745/left-join-вытащить-все-совпадения

Comment: Пытался, не выходит

Comment: легче один раз сделать нормально базу, чем все время вот такие проблемы получать